# Combining two arrays while excluding rows that are found in both

Tags: arrays, matlab, duplicates, set, xor

I have two arrays:

```
a = [1 2; 2 3; 4 5];
b = [2 5; 1 2; 6 9];
```

now I want to create a new array `c` that will not contain the rows that are same in both arrays (`a` and `b`). So the `c` array will look like

```
c = [2 3; 4 5; 2 5; 6 9];
```

How can I do that? Is there any command that I can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [`setxor`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setxor.html) with `rows` option. The default of this function is to order the rows in ascending order, but if you want to keep the original order, you can use the `stable` option:

```
c=setxor(a,b,'rows','stable')

c =

 2     3
 4     5
 2     5
 6     9
```

Comment: how can I can delete duplicated rows from an array? if I have a=[ 1 2; 3 4; 1 2]. So I want to get c=[3 4]. Is there any command for this?

Answer (score 1):

Please show the attempts you made so far in your next question.

```
c= [a(~ismember(a,b,'rows'),:);b(~ismember(b,a,'rows'),:)]
```